# How to put an app running locally online?

Tags: mongodb

I have an app working perfectly locally (http://localhost:8080/) and now I want to make it visible online. How to do so?
The app is running with Mongodb by the way.

I didn't try anything yet since I have no idea where to start with.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "make it visible online" what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is what you're looking for [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). It works as a reverse proxy exposing your `localhost` app to the world. This is very useful for testing your app, showing to a friend and last but not least to test something like `webhooks` from `Stripe` for example. Hope this helps you. Cheers, sigfried.

Answer (score 0):

What language/framework is the app written in?  A service like https://www.heroku.com/ is pretty easy to set up.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a server. There a several cloud server provider (e.g. AWS, Heroku) to choose from. For step by step setup instructions you can see the corresponding documentation:

AWS: 
https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/mongodb/?nc1=h_ls

Heroku: 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api#provision-a-mongodb-database

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cloud service provider to spin up a server such as Amazon Web Services, Heroku or Google Cloud Platform. Perhaps you might also like mLab or composethe links are below:

[Google Cloud Platform](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas/mongodb-google-cloud)

[MongoDB on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/mongodb/)

[Heroku & MongoDB](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab)

[mLab](https://mlab.com/)

[compose](https://www.compose.com/)

Below are tutorials for them respectively:

[Tutorial on using Heroku and MongoDB](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-mongodb-with-a-node-application-on-heroku)

[Using Google Cloud and MongoDB](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/mongodb-atlas-appengineflex-nodejs-app)

[Overview of Amazon Web Services and MongoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/overview.html)

P.S: As you do this think of which one to use think scalability of your app, security of your app and other factors. Good luck!